# net-snmp ubuntu - snmptrapd doesn't log in mysql

Tags: mysql, logging, net-snmp

snmptrapd doesn't log in mysql

ISSUE - net-snmp does not log traps into the mysql database - Installed on Ubuntu

Net-snmp was configured with the following as per the tutorial - http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu

I configured snmpdtrapd as mentioned on the following page.
http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmptrapd

My mysql installation was running with no issues, however it did not contain mysql_config file - so I ran the following install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev – will get mysql_config file
```

Mysql continues to run with no issues

net-snmp configuration was run with the following command successfully
    ./configure --with-defaults --with-mysql

the config output showed that mysql logging was enabled.

```
cat snmptrapd.conf ---------------
authCommunity log public

 # maximum number of traps to queue before forced flush
 # set to 1 to immediately write to the database
 sqlMaxQueue 1

 # seconds between periodic queue flushes
```

### sqlSaveInterval 1

```
cat  snmpd.conf   - contains as its line1 & line 2 -------------------
rwcommunity public localhost
```

---

```
linux@lin-850:~$ cat my.cnf 
[snmptrapd]
user=root
password=qbcdfee
host=localhost
```

The following command runs well with appropriate output

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost
```

db schema was made as per - /net-snmp-5.7.3/dist/schema-snmptrapd.sql

Where did I go wrong - pls help. Thanks in advance

regs

George